# Find out negative adverbs using NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis

Since adjectives and verbs are able to convey negative sentiments using negative prefixes, I need to find out such phrases from millions of sentences that I have. For example " I am not good at this." is a negative sentence even if "good" is a positive word.

I am using nltk to tag all the sentences. But how would I be able to filter out negative prefixes? Most of negative prefixes like no, not are tagged as adverbs "RB". Does that mean I can use all tagged adverbs as negative prefix? And also the data that I have is huge which makes it difficult for me to come up with a list of negative prefixes.

Comment: You need to read up on the topic, this can't be answered here in full. You need to do negation detection, then negation *scope* detection, then you might need to look at itensifiers as well... This is all a whole area of research, not just a minor technical problem.

Comment: My bad, but I do have an algorithm to find out negative phrases but is there a way to tag negative prefixes only using any tool available? My main research theme is something else so I don't want to spend anymore time gathering the data

Comment: @ntstha "Negative phrases" (as in: negative sentiment) aren't the same as negated constituents. But sure, you can do some bad approximation, the question is how bad of a heuristic are you willing to accept.

Comment: You're at a programing website. Open-ended NLP algorithms are too broad a topic. If you already have an algorithm, what exactly do you need help with? Narrow down your question and maybe someone can help.  (And what on earth do you mean by "negative prefix"? "not" is not a prefix).

Answer (score 1):

NLTK has an API for  `sentiwordnet` but that might not help you with your task. [Sentiwordnet](http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it) comes with its kinks. E.g.

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import sentiwordnet as swn
# Kind of useful.
>>> swn.senti_synsets('happy', 'a')
[SentiSynset('happy.a.01'), SentiSynset('felicitous.s.02'), SentiSynset('glad.s.02'), SentiSynset('happy.s.04')]
>>> swn.senti_synsets('happy', 'a')[0].synset.definition()
u'enjoying or showing or marked by joy or pleasure'
>>> swn.senti_synsets('happy', 'a')[0].pos_score()
0.875
>>> swn.senti_synsets('happy', 'a')[0].neg_score()
0.0
>>> swn.senti_synsets('happy', 'a')[0].obj_score()
0.125

# Not very useful...
>>> swn.senti_synsets('slow', 'a')
>>> swn.senti_synsets('slow', 'a')[0].synset.definition()
u'not moving quickly; taking a comparatively long time'
>>> swn.senti_synsets('slow', 'a')[0].pos_score()
0.0
>>> swn.senti_synsets('slow', 'a')[0].neg_score()
0.0
>>> swn.senti_synsets('slow', 'a')[0].obj_score()
1.0
```

There's also the [VADER algorithm](http://comp.social.gatech.edu/papers/icwsm14.vader.hutto.pdf) in NLTK http://www.nltk.org/howto/sentiment.html:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('vader_lexicon')
>>> from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
>>> sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
>>> sid.polarity_scores('happy')
{'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.0, 'pos': 1.0, 'compound': 0.5719}
>>> sid.polarity_scores('sad')
{'neg': 1.0, 'neu': 0.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': -0.4767}
>>> sid.polarity_scores('sad man')
{'neg': 0.756, 'neu': 0.244, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': -0.4767}
>>> sid.polarity_scores('not so happy')
{'neg': 0.616, 'neu': 0.384, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': -0.4964}
```